# How to make multiple independent columns and then fill them horizontally?

Tags: boxes, columns, layout, author

I am implementing an idea for rendering authors. As far as I could see no other package could do it for me, but I am happy to be corrected. The idea is to place authors in several independent columns, but my current question is specifically about badness I am getting in MWE.

As a first step I wanted to create 3 independent columns and fill them with content. I have added a bit of glue to separate the columns in case lines gets too close. It does what I wanted, but I am getting overfull warning

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{
    \noindent{}Item 1

    Item 4

    Item 7
  }
  \hskip 10pt plus 5pt minus 5pt\relax
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
    \noindent{}Item 2

    Item 5 is a little bit longer

    Item 8
  }
  \hskip 10pt plus 5pt minus 5pt\relax
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
    \noindent{}Item 3

    Item 6
  }
}

\end{document}
```

I can make it go away, by either centering or decreasing the width of my horizontal box, but can anyone explain why? I feel that I am still abusing rather than using the macros.

If there's a better way of achieving this effect, please let me know. I decided to go with boxes rather than tables, but I am happy to revisit. I thought boxes were more natural when you don't know the number of columns and rows beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get

```
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--28
```

as your outer `\makebox` is indented by `\parindent` so `\noindent` would fix that, but you may also get overfull boxes from the inner list.

You have  a `\textwidth` box containing

```
SPACE .3\textwidth SPACE 10pt  .3\textwidth SPACE 10pt .3\textwidth SPACE
```

so may or may not fit, depending if 4 word spaces + 20pt is bigger than .1\textwidth.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%%%%
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
    Item 1

    Item 4

    Item 7
  }\hfill
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
    Item 2

    Item 5 is a little bit longer

    Item 8
  }\hfill
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
   Item 3

    Item 6
  }%%%%
}

\end{document}
```

The ends of lines marked `%` don't need to be commented, but good practice. Those marked `%%%%` are needed to avoid bad spaces.

---

One reason that tabulars are often used for this sort of layout is that three equal width boxes, while technically equally spaced and spanning full width, look shifted left if there is a possiblity of having short entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hrule

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%%%%
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{
    Item 1

    Item 4

    Item 7
  }\hfill
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
    Item 2

    Item 5 is a little bit longer

    Item 8
  }\hfill
  \parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{%
   Item 3

    Item 6
  }%%%
}

\bigskip

\hrule

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%%%%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Item 1\\
    Item 4\\
    Item 7
   \end{tabular}\hfill
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    Item 2\\
    Item 5 is a little bit longer\\
    Item 8
   \end{tabular}\hfill
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
   Item 3\\
    Item 6
   \end{tabular}%%%
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlile. Yes, I clearly forgot about the `\parindent`!